# Bulk conveyors are rounding batch sizes and losing material... What causes this and how do you fix it?

Tags: anylogic, bulk

[image]

In my model I have bulk conveyors filling tanks throughout the model, and delays which are stopped upon the tanks becoming full with a delay.stopDelayForAll() command. However, occasionally the tanks fill up to 999.999 / 1000 and never completely fill due to some amount being rounded and lost on the bulk conveyor (as shown in the console warning in the picture), so my agents in the delay blocks get stuck and never leave the delay. When this happens, the conveyor shows that it is still moving and still has some material (on the order of anywhere from 1E-6 to 1E-3 kilograms), but this material never actually flows to the tank.

I have a variable (type double) called d_conveyorThroughputTPH representing the throughput in tons per hour, and in the conveyor I had the tons/sec input set to d_conveyorThroughputTPH/3600 - I initially thought the machine precision of this division was causing the rounding error, but even after changing that conveyor parameter to roundToDecimal(d_conveyorThroughputTPH/3600, 3), the issue still persists.

My conveyor lengths are 'Defined by conveyor belt shape' and the speeds are 500fpm.

Does anybody know what may be the cause of this issue, or how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fluid library has some tolerance levels that apply that can cause this problem
https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/fluid-library/index.html#handling-numeric-errors

The biggest issue with this, is that in a model, this might happen with such an extremely low probability that it's easy to get confused

It's not super easy to find a solution.